# Display database table on HTML page without leaving HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have an HTML page. I would like to create a few buttons and forms in order to display database information on my page. I could have several forms that call external PHP files that then print their own HTML, but I want to have the user stay on `mysite.com/home.html`.

Is there any way I can call external PHP files to display my database tables on my HTML page without leaving the `home.html` page? I don't want to echo over everything on the home page, so I'd imagine I need to make use of a `<div id="printableArea">` element on `home.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a way to call external PHP routes.

You can use the jQuery Ajax (*Asynchronous JavaScript and XML*) method for this.
Ajax send HTTP request like a normal HTML formular, but the benefit of ajax is that ajax works asynchron, that means that you are able to send POST / GET request without reloading the whole page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/demo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
       // data includes the reponse of your php file.
    }
});
```

Your PHP file should send a response like this:

```
// $data should include your database informations
$data = array();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

If you have any question, just feel free to ask.